# How to programmatically select cell in collectionView in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I'm new to swift and been having trouble programmatically selecting collectionview cells in collectionView. I've found only instructions for tableview but ran into an error when tried to implement it.

```
 let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    appsCollectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .bottom)
    appsCollectionView.delegate?.collectionView!(appsCollectionView, didSelectItemAt: indexPath)
```

According to other answers, you need both lines 2 and 3. Not sure what line 3 is doing. When I try to run this code, I got the error

```
collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Thanks!

Comment: please, accept an answer.

Answer (score 3):

This error basically just tells you that you didn't implement the `UICollectionViewDelegate` protocol `collectionView(_,didSelectItemAt:_)` method, but I don't think you are supposed to call the method directly (line 3).

I'm pretty sure calling `selectItem(at:,animated:,scrollPosition:)` (line 2) is enough. The collection view should scroll to the selected cell and the cell appearance should change to the selected state. But maybe your cell appearance doesn't change when selected, which makes you believe it's not selected?

If it's not already the case, in your `UICollectionViewCell` subclass, override the following properties and, for example, change the color of some label:

```
override var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        titleLabel.textColor = isHighlighted || isSelected ? .black : .darkGray
    }
}

override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        titleLabel.textColor = isHighlighted || isSelected ? .black : .darkGray
    }
}
```

Then try to call only `selectItem(at:,animated:,scrollPosition:)` and maybe you'll notice a difference.

Note: As written in the `selectItem(at:,animated:,scrollPosition:)` method documentation:

> This method does not cause any selection-related delegate methods to be called.

It will just change the cell state to selected, not call any action that would have been called if you would have tapped on the cell.

Comment: hmm so it looks like the selected cells actually change colors when they're selected. BUT, my entire collection view  (the parent view of the cell) disappears after I execute the first two lines. There are no errors in the console either?

Comment: my function   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    } is not really called either...

Comment: How is the collection view disappearing exactly? Is its `contentOffset` moving to a value where there are no cell to display?

`selectItem(at:,animated:,scrollPosition:)` won't call `didSelectItemAt` as stated in the documentation. Just call the code you want manually.

Comment: The whole collectionview isn't disappearing I guess because the background color is still there. The cells in the collectionview are disappearing is what I'm seeing. I thought it might try to scroll to the selected cell position, but I printed out the content offset of the collection view and it's still (0.0, 0.0) after i called appsCollectionView.selectItem

Comment: I tried other functions such as appsCollectionView.scrollToItem() and the same is happening also

Comment: I don't think `selectItem(at:,animated:,scrollPosition:)` can be the cause of the cells disappearing. Are you sure there's not any other code called right before or after calling `selectItem`?

Comment: i posted my full code above^ could my custom layout be the problem?

Comment: If you don't call `appsCollectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .top)` do the cells appear properly?
Since you're using a custom layout there might be many reasons your cells don't appear.

Answer (score 1):

> According to other answers, you need both lines 2 and 3. Not sure what
>   line 3 is doing. When I try to run this code, I got the error
>
> collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent
>   to instance

You do not need to call the collectionView delegate method explicity. Instead, if you have just set the delegate then just implement the method.

```
optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
             didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Comment: I tried just calling selectItem (as noted by Ferschae Naej) without the last line but it appears that my cells disappeared from my view without error in console - what might be the issue here?

Comment: So did you check that if your cell exist at that indexpath?

Comment: @xcalysta share your full code .. your code little bit confusing

Comment: I'm sure the cell exists because it displays correctly, right..? I also added full code.